# SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "SPAREBOX": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and want to calculate sum of sum following as:

table LOG0104M:

```
 PRODUCT_CODE     TOTAL_QUANTITY     PACKING_STYLE     QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
 112677           1                  30                 1
 111202           1                  80                 1
```

my query: **(UPDATED)**

```
SELECT 
   log04.PRODUCT_CODE,
   log04.TOTAL_QUANTITY,
   log04.PACKING_STYLE,
   log04.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN,
   /*
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY + PACKING_STYLE) AS FULLBOX,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS SPAREBOX,
   SUM(FULLBOX + SPAREBOX) AS BOX
    */
    SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY * 2 + PACKING_STYLE - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS BOX1
FROM 
   LOG0104M log04
GROUP BY 
    log04.PRODUCT_CODE
```

I want to sum 'FULLBOX' and 'SPAREBOX' but it happen error following as:

```
/* SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "SPAREBOX": invalid identifier */
SQL Error [979] [42000]: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

How to fix the problem

Comment: yes i see, i will change it

Comment: You can't do that... either wrap it in a CTE and then reference those, or just expand out the expressions.  Sum (TOTAL_QUANTITY * 2 + PACKING_STYLE - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN).  There are some cases where you can (for example in the group by clause), but not like that.

Comment: Hi @Hambone i wish you can give me more detail

Comment: @Hambone: i have try your suggestion, it happen an error: SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Ugh...  this is ugly for a comment, but it doesn't seem to warrant an expanded answer.  CTE = Common Table Expression.  `with box_query as ( <<your query here>> ) select b.*, b.fullbox + b.sparebox as box from box_query b`

Comment: Aah, okay, that error is unrelated to your question.  Any expression that does not have an aggregate function applied needs to be included in a "group by" clause at the end of your query.  So "group by product_code, ..." and every other field except the summed fields

Comment: @Hambone: i have updated code, could you review it ?

Comment: Officially exceeded chat limitations...  please see answer and see how close they get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add the raw data and the desired output, I could confirm for sure, but I think you want one of these two:

```
SELECT 
   log04.PRODUCT_CODE,
   log04.TOTAL_QUANTITY,
   log04.PACKING_STYLE,
   log04.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY + PACKING_STYLE) AS FULLBOX,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS SPAREBOX,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY * 2 + PACKING_STYLE - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS BOX
FROM 
   LOG0104M log04
group by
  product_code, total_quantity, packing_style, quantity_in_full_ctn
```

I don't think that's what you intended...  my guess is you want this:

```
SELECT 
   log04.PRODUCT_CODE,
   sum (log04.TOTAL_QUANTITY) as total_quantity,
   sum (log04.PACKING_STYLE) as packing_style
   sum (log04.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) as quantity_in_full_ctn,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY + PACKING_STYLE) AS FULLBOX,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS SPAREBOX,
   SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY * 2 + PACKING_STYLE - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS BOX
FROM 
   LOG0104M log04
group by
  product_code
```

Or some variant of it.

If you don't apply an aggregate (sum, min, max, whatever), then it has to be included in the group by.  Once it's in the group by, the data will be segmented by that, meaning the first query will have multiple lines per product code, but the second one will only have each product code listed once, which I *think* is what you want.